# Div containers out of place when too much content is added

Tags: html, containers

I have made a page which will contain a number of 'boxes' each having a recipe in and description etc. When live and fully coded (php to be added too soon). The amount of content in each box will differ, if you view the page right now it looks fine, but I stress tested it by adding in loads more description text in one of the containers and it breaks the layout.

This is to eventually be handed over to a developer to do all the PHP etc, but wondered what ideas people had to fix this issue (in PHP too if best, then ill just pass on the message/ideas.)

Here is the live url of the page when it looks fine.  - http://jordancharters.co.uk/testarea/boxes.html

Here is the same page but with a container having too much content (which may happen when the client adds in more text than I initially imagined them to do). Breaks the layout. - http://jordancharters.co.uk/testarea/boxes2.html

Looking for a solution in either HTML or PHP etc. (Im just a front end developer.)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to give the boxrecipes-container class a fixed height in your style.css line 902, and also add an overflow:overlay attribute, so that the huge text is shown with a scroll bar.
overflow:hidden will hide the extra text with a fixed height but your title is not click able, so to make the "Select Recipe" button visible the overflow should be overlay.

Try the below code hope it is useful

```
.boxrecipes-container {
padding: 10px;
width: 430px;
height: 230px;
overflow: overlay;
background-color: #eee;
display: block;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-top: 20px;
position: relative;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: if you don't want scroll bars in your blocks, another option is to strip ur text to some characters before showing it on the block with the help of php substr('$Your_variable_that_has_description', 0, 80); //80 is arbitrary you can use the no of characters you want. and to be on a safe side add height to the boxrecipes-container class in the style.css